# Do asymptotically equivalent coefficients survive convolution at least in Θ?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, generating-functions, convolution

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/881423/3330) where I asked if asymptotic equivalence of coefficients carried over after convolution, resp. why this was not the case. Answerer [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) [proposed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/881423#comment1819485_881505) that a weaker form may hold under certain conditions. This question is to explore this further and provide some information about the connection to my original problem, which has since become clearer.

Let $f$, $\tilde f$ and $g$ ordinary generating functions with the following properties.

- $f$, $\tilde f$ and $g$ have the same radius of convergence $0 < \rho < 1$.
- $[z^n]f(z)$ and $[z^n]g(z)$ are positive integers and non-decreasing.
- $[z^n]f(z) \sim [z^n]\tilde f(z)$ for $n \to \infty$.

The question is if

$\qquad\displaystyle [z^n](f \ast g)(z) \overset{?}{\in} \Theta\bigl( [z^n](\tilde f \ast g)(z) \bigr)$,

that is if the coefficients of the [(discrete) convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Multiplication_yields_convolution) remain within $\Theta$-bounds if we exchange $f$ for $\tilde f$.

#### Background

I know for some class of formal languages that for every $\alpha$ in some subset of dyadic numbers, there is a language $L$ with

$\qquad |L_n| \sim c \cdot d^n \cdot n^{\alpha}$

where $c$ and $d$ are suitable constants. While I do not know the exact generating function $F_L$ of such a language -- or don't want to bother with it technically -- I can come up with

$\qquad F(z) = 1 \pm (1-dz)^{-\alpha-1}$

which has the same asymptotic behaviour in coefficients (up to factor $c$ which I happily ignore). Now I take the Cartesian with some fixed language $L_B$ and ask for

$\qquad |(L \times L_B)_n| \in \Theta(?)$.

If I can use $F$ instead of $F_L$ and still get the same $\Theta$ (see above), I can answer this question (more easily).

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to take $\rho=1$? I don't see any loss of generality.

Comment: In my application, I have $\rho < 1$ (since the languages usually grow exponentially; the others are (probably) boring). If a proof is easier for $\rho = 1$ but extends to smaller $\rho$, go ahead. (I lack the knowledge/skill to see what impact that can have.)

Comment: The reason I think it's WLOG is that if $f(z)$ has radius of convergence $\rho$, then taking $z=\rho w$ gives you $f(w)$ with unit radius of convergence. (I may be overlooking something, though.)

Comment: I was able to solve the issue in my special application case by 0) picking a simple $L_B$ (OGF $(1-dz)^{-1}$), 1) applying the definition of $\sim$ and $\lim$ subsequently and 2) choosing a generous $\varepsilon$ for the lower bound. We indeed have $\Theta$-equality of the convolution's coefficients in this case.